# Integrate PHPT test cases with PHPUnit

Tags: php, phpunit, phpt

How can I get PHPUnit to run my [PHPT test cases](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php) and integrate the pass/fail status into the overall metrics? I am already aware of how to run these tests using [`run-phpt`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.commands.runphpt.php) from the command line, but I want to run them from within PHPUnit with my other tests.

I'm aware that the `PHPUnit_Extensions_PhptTestCase` exists but I couldn't find any samples on how to use it.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Thanks for the cleanup. Reads way better now. Much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the main point of this [blog post about testing file uploads](http://qafoo.com/blog/013_testing_file_uploads_with_php.html) is to describe how to write PHPT tests, it shows how to integrate them into PHPUnit at the end of the post. In short, you pass the absolute path to the `.phpt` file to the parent constructor.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Extensions/PhptTestCase.php';

class UploadExampleTest extends PHPUnit_Extensions_PhptTestCase {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(__DIR__ . '/upload-example.phpt');
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `PHPUnit_Extensions_PhptTestSuite` class, that takes a directory as its first constructor argument and then searches for all *.phpt files within this directory.

Comment: That means that every single testcase requires a distinct hard-coded class file **and** testcase file for it?  Wow, that's useless...

Comment: i totally forgot about mapi s' post even so that was the reason i started caring about phpt again. Thanks !

Comment: @ircmaxell: "Alternatively, you can use the PHPUnit_Extensions_PhptTestSuite class, that takes a directory as its first constructor argument and then searches for all *.phpt files within this directory" :)

Comment: @edorian: I had always wondered what PHPT was all about, and that post presents a great example. We have an avatar-upload controller that will be getting a unit test soon. :)

Comment: This is really not working for me. Is there any setup requied to get this to work? Everytime I try to run the tests (either with PhpTestCase or PhpTestSuite) the runner just breaks (not even a fail, just dies)... every time I run it phpunit complains that the class cannot be found in the file :/ Is there anything else I need other than the example above?

Comment: @DavidHarkness Yes the phpt works perfectly outside PHPUnit I'll setup my tests again and post my code. Thankyou for the reply

Comment: @DavidHarkness First of all, +1 for pointing me to gist... Awesome tool... Secondly...https://gist.github.com/4029107

I could not create directories, but the two files should be obvious which directories to put them in. I've also included output of my tests, Any help much appreciated!

Comment: @Matt - As noted in [PHPUnit #639](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/639), this broke sometime during 3.6's development. I imagine it should be fixed relatively soon, but I posted the solution there if you want to make the change locally.

Comment: @DavidHarkness thankyou for the update. I'm running a older version (so its compatible with our development with zend framework 1) phpunit 3.3.17. So I guess its not the same bug. When I get some time I'll have a poke around the code :)

Answer (score 4):

In your phpunit XML configuration, you can add a testsuite named *PHPT* (or any other name) and point to the directory where you placed the `.phpt` files with the *suffix* set to "`.phpt`". Phpunit will then execute all phpt-test-files from that directory:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Main Test Suite">
        <directory>test</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="PHPT Test Suite">
        <directory suffix=".phpt">test/phpt</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

In this example, the directory `test/phpt` contains the `.phpt` files.

Information about the format how `.phpt` tests are structured and written is available in depth at:

- [Creating new test files (PHP: Quality Assurance)](https://qa.php.net/write-test.php)