# Erroneous failure running PHPT with PHPUnit on PHP 5.4.6

Tags: php, phpunit, phpt

PHPUnit runs regular tests without trouble, but it mistakenly reports this [basic PHPT example](http://qa.php.net/write-test.php#basic-format) as failing when it should pass:

```
--TEST--
strtr() function - basic test for strstr()
--FILE--
<?php
/* Do not change this test it is a README.TESTING example. */
$trans = array("hello"=>"hi", "hi"=>"hello", "a"=>"A", "world"=>"planet");
var_dump(strtr("# hi all, I said hello world! #", $trans));
?>
--EXPECT--
string(32) "# hello All, I sAid hi planet! #"
```

Running this with `phpunit basic-format.phpt` gives

```
There was 1 failure:

1) basic-format.php
--- Expeccted
+++ Actual
@@ @@
- # hello All, I sAid hi planet! #
+
```

I'm using Windows / PHP 5.4.6. The test works fine with PHP 5.4.0, but I'm unable to determine any discrepancy other than php version.

Comment: That's because .phpt files aren't phpunit test files - they are for PHP's internal testing utility

Comment: how does one run a .phpt test ?
I know it works just fine on one installation of I have of PHP/PHPUnit
here's one thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922207/docs-examples-on-how-to-use-phpt-test-cases-with-phpunit

Comment: So what does your phpunit test script look like? Or what do you get if you execute php's run-tests against that phpt file?

Comment: `C:\php\tests\path\tests>phpunit AllTests.php  
    PHPUnit 3.6.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.  
      
    Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.75Mb  

    There was 1 failure:  

    1) C:\php\tests\path\tests\basic.phpt  
    --- Expected  
    +++ Actual  
    @@ @@  
    -string(32) "# hello All, I sAid hi planet! #"  
    +  

    C:\php\phpunit:46  

    FAILURES!  
    Tests: 82, Assertions: 153, Failures: 1.`

sorry, not sure how to format my comment
nutshell all the tests work, sans .phpt

Comment: sorry... now I see you're referring to "php's run-tests"
is this an executable, php command line switch, .php file, other
how do I install or learn more?

Comment: C:\php\tests\path\tests>pear run-tests  /
Running 1 tests  /
PASS strtr() function - basic test for strstr()[basic.phpt]  /
TOTAL TIME: 00:00  /
1 PASSED TESTS / 
0 SKIPPED TESTS

Comment: I assume the php 5.4.0, where it works, is also Windows? Can you post a _diff_ of the output from `phpinfo` on the two installs? (On linux you can do that with a one-liner, see http://darrendev.blogspot.com/2010/11/bash-tips-meld-on-program-output.html ; for Windows it most likely requires a bit of copy-and-paste into an online diff tool )

Comment: @MarkBaker phpunit is able to execute .phpt test cases. They are used internally for it's own regression test suite for example.

Comment: What happens when you run the test using PEAR? `pear run-tests basic-format.phpt`