# How to simulate file upload in php command line

Tags: phpunit, php

I'm new to PHPUnit testing framework.

as we know that `move_uploaded_file()` function of PHP will not work until the file is uploaded via http POST method

So, the Question is how to simulate this in PHP command line

Note: using selenium we can simulate webform.. but i need another alternative.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically need to make your code more testable. Break it down so you can test the simple act of uploading a file through HTTP separately from the rest of the code. The primary use of `move_uploaded_file` is to put in an extra security stop so you cannot be tricked into moving some other file, `move_uploaded_file` simply makes sure that the file was uploaded in the same request and then moves it. You can simply move the file using `rename` as well. As such, break your application down to have one `Request` object which represents and encapsulates the current HTTP request, including making it check uploaded files using `is_uploaded_file`. Once that's validated, you can use `rename` instead of `move_uploaded_file`. In your tests you can then mock the `Request` object and test your other code.

You can also simply make `move_uploaded_file` mockable, for example like this:

```
class Foo {

    public function do() {
        ...
        $this->move_uploaded_file($from, $to);
        ...
    }

    protected function move_uploaded_file($from, $to) {
        return move_uploaded_file($from, $to);
    }

}
```

In your tests you can extend/mock the class and override `Foo::move_uploaded_file` to always `return true`, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the [PHP Testing Framework](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php) (PHPT) comes in. It is installed with PEAR and allows you to feed HTTP requests, I/O operations, file uploads, etc. to a PHP script by writing a `.phpt` file and executing it with [`run-phpt`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.commands.runphpt.php) or `pear run-tests <file.phpt>`. You can also [run them with PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4925061/285873) using `PhptTestCase` and `PhptTestSuite`.

To simulate a file upload you need to use the [`--POST_RAW--` section](http://qa.php.net/phpt_details.php#post_raw_section) with the same data the browser sends. This is the example from the PHP QAT site:

> **Important:** Unfortunately, the example on their site fails without any explanation.

**is_uploaded_file.phpt**

```
--TEST--
is_uploaded_file() function
--CREDITS--
Dave Kelsey <d_kelsey@uk.ibm.com>
--SKIPIF--
<?php if (php_sapi_name()=='cli') die('skip'); ?>
--POST_RAW--
Content-type: multipart/form-data, boundary=AaB03x

--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="field1"

Joe Blow
--AaB03x
content-disposition: form-data; name="pics"; filename="file1.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

abcdef123456789
--AaB03x--
--FILE--
<?php
// uploaded file
var_dump(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pics']['tmp_name']));

// not an uploaded file
var_dump(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['pics']['name']));

// not an uploaded file
var_dump(is_uploaded_file('random_filename.txt'));

// not an uploaded file
var_dump(is_uploaded_file('__FILE__'));

// Error cases
var_dump(is_uploaded_file());
var_dump(is_uploaded_file('a', 'b'));

?>
--EXPECTF--
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)

Warning: is_uploaded_file() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in %s on line %d
NULL

Warning: is_uploaded_file() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given in %s on line %d
NULL
```

**Running**

```
pear run-tests --cgi=PHPCGI is_uploaded_file.phpt
```

Manuel Pichler wrote up an example in a [blog post](http://qafoo.com/blog/013_testing_file_uploads_with_php.html), but it fails as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use PHPUnit to test file upload without mocking out the actual `move_uploaded_file` check you can use `.phpt` test cases, which PHPUnit can execute, so simulate a web request.

Basically you create a `.phpt` file that looks like this:

## Standalone example: `uploadTest.phpt`

```
--TEST--
Example test emulating a file upload
--POST_RAW--
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn

------WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Qafoo provides quality assurance support and consulting

------WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn--
--FILE--
<?php

var_dump(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));

?>
--EXPECT--
bool(true)
```

run using `phpunit uploadTest.phpt`

---

For the full explanation check out the blog post describing the details:

[**`http://qafoo.com/blog/013_testing_file_uploads_with_php.html`**](http://qafoo.com/blog/013_testing_file_uploads_with_php.html)

Also: [**`There is working sample code over at github`**](https://github.com/Qafoo/blog-examples/tree/master/testing_file_uploads.)

---

## More verbose real world example:

```
--TEST--
Example test emulating a file upload
--POST_RAW--
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn

------WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="example.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Qafoo provides quality assurance support and consulting

------WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

Upload
------WebKitFormBoundaryfywL8UCjFtqUBTQn--
--FILE--
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/UploadExample.php';

$upload = new UploadExample('/tmp');
$upload->handle('file');

var_dump(file_exists('/tmp/example.txt'));
?>
--EXPECT--
bool(true)
```

Comment: Does this example work for you? I cannot even get the simple `POST_RAW` example from qa.php.net to work, and there's no clue what the failure is. I'm running PHP 5.3.10-1 on Xubuntu.

Comment: @DavidHarkness I've edited the question with a standalone example that works nicely for me. 5.3 & 5.4 ubuntu using PHPUnit 3.6 & 3.7.

Comment: PHPUnit 3.7.9 skips the test. Is there any way to determine why it's being skipped?

Comment: @DavidHarkness if you're still interested, 3 years later...I was not able to run tests which use post_raw unless I specify the CGI parameter like this `pear run-tests --cgi=C:\xampp\php\php-cgi.exe C:\xampp\htdocs\PC_administration_interface\Controler\Test\Test_interface_builder/invalid_file.phpt`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like the answer given by [deceze](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13564397/2408964) above.

However, another possibility is the use of [namespaces](http://pierrerambaud.com/blog/php/2012-12-29-testing-upload-file-with-php).

The code for this is on [Github](https://github.com/PierreRambaud/blog/blob/master/testing-upload-file-with-php/tests/Bootstrap.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can do file uploads from the command line with [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/):

```
curl --form input-name=@filename http://localhost/upload.php
```

with `input-name` being the name of the input field in the HTML normally used and `filename` being path and name of the file to be uploaded - remember to put them in quotes or escape special character if they contain some.

However, this obviously still requires running the script from a webserver and apparently that is not what you want, so see [How can I write tests for file upload in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402765/how-can-i-write-tests-for-file-upload-in-php) for ways to test file uploads with PHPUnit.